# Fluid height with a non fixed header

Tags: html, css

I need to have an webpage with a header and a content part.

The content of the header will be of variable height, the content also. The page should be 100% and if the content div overflows it should display a scroll bar (only for the content div not the whole page).

I want to keep away from JQuery/JS solutions and solve this with CSS (sass?)

```
<div class="body"><!-- 100% height -->
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>Variable content with max-height</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    div.body{
        height: 100%;
    }
    div.header{
        max-height: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    div.footer{
        overflow-y: ???
        /* 100% - height of header */
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```css
div.body {
    height: 100%;
}

div.header {
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
    max-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.content {
    height:240px;
    overflow:scroll;
}

div.footer {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="body"><!-- 100% height -->
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>Variable content with max-height</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <h2>Footer</h2>
        <p>I'm a footert</p>
    </div>        
</div>
```

**UPDATE (with absolute positioning):**

The following should meet your requirements :)

```css
.header {
    /* remove me - test purpose only */
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
    text-align: center;
    /* end of test purpose */
    
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
}

.content {
    top:100px;
    bottom:100px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;        
    
    position:absolute;
    overflow:auto;
}

.footer {
    /* remove me - test purpose only */
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    text-align: center;
    /* end of test purpose */
    
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="body"><!-- 100% height -->
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>Variable content with max-height</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
        <p>Variable content with scroll-y</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <h2>Footer</h2>
        <p>I'm a footert</p>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: I want to have a full screen page, this limits the content to a fixed 240 px.

Comment: Ah okay, I'm understanding now.. give me a few seconds and I'll post a new answer, that might work.

Comment: try the new code snippet. Use "full page" if you run the code snippet, to see the result!

Comment: The header is max 100px, now you fix the content with 100px while the header could be less then 100px. There will be a gap when the header is smaller due to content.

Comment: Hmm.. You'll require some jQuery to add dynamic to absolute positioned elements. This would only require the following code to solve that problem: `$(".content").css('top', $('.header').height());`.. Note: If using this, I would  recommend to make the header-div as a id instead -> #header.

Comment: I've stated I don't want to use jQuery. Was hoping that there was a better solution.